# Import 3D array from MAT-file using C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I would like to know if there is a way to know the 'z' dimension of a 3D array when reading data from a 'MAT-file' using the MATLAB API. I've implemented a function to load the data from file as follows:

```
double* importMATFile(const char* i_file)
{
    MATFile *pMF;
    // open MAT-file
    pMF = matOpen(i_file, "r");
    // check for file errors

    // Matlab Array Data
    mxArray *mArrayData;
    // Matlab Variable Name
    const char* mVarName = NULL;
    // read data from file
    mArrayData = matGetNextVariable(pMF, &mVarName);

    // pointer to mxArray data
    double *dataPtr; 
    dataPtr = (double*) mxGetPr(mArrayData);

    // NOTE MATLAB work in COLUMN-MAJOR order

    // dimension of the array : rows
    int32_t NROWS = mxGetM(mArrayData);
    // Right now the z dimension must be known a priori
    int32_t NDEPTH = 32
    // dimension of the array : cols
    int32_t NCOLS = mxGetN(mArrayData) / NDEPTH;

    return dataPtr;
}
```

I'm stuck when getting the DEPTH value, in order to know the number of columns. I've have noticed that the result of the function **mxGetNumberOfDimensions(mArrayData)** is **3**, so, the API knows there are three dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is [mxGetDimensions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mxgetdimensions.html). It will return the size of each of the dimensions. This should work for any number of dimensions, not just 3.